# How to align side bar beneath content if not floated

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I am leaning responsive design and i came across this problem.

the image below shows all
[image]

1. A shows how the layout with be on large screen
2. B shows how i want it to be on narrow screens by removing the **float:right;**
3. C shows what i get after removing float:right on the sidebar.

below is an exam of the code i am using

```
  <doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
  #container{width:100%; height:700px; background:blue; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; padding:10px;}
 #box{width:60%; height:70px; background:black;}
 #content{width:70%; height:600px; float:left; background:green; margin-top:10px;}
 #aside{width:30%; height:800px; float:none; clear:right; background:yellow;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
<div id="box">
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>

<div id="aside">
</div>


 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/cBh6z/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution with NO floats:

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cBh6z/1/)

```
 body{margin:0;min-width:500px;}
 #container{color:white;width:100%; height:700px; background:blue;padding:10px}
 #box{width:60%; height:70px; background:black;margin-bottom:10px}
 #content{width:60%; height:300px;background:lightgreen;margin-bottom:10px}
 #aside{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:30%; height:400px;background:green;margin:10px  10px 0 0}
 @media(max-width: 500px){#aside{position:static}}
```

Comment: and another downvote with no comments ... I just hate jealous people.

Comment: If the question had been "how do I achieve this without floats?" that would be one thing. If he'd asked for your opinion about media query usage and best practices, that too would be an entirely different animal. IMO, this is like suggesting free-running to someone who has never heard of it and has only just learned to walk.

Comment: He doesn't ask how to ... if you pay attention to the question, he only says he has a problem. This is one way to solve it, there are others, all solutions should be welcome, don't you think @Frankenscarf?

Comment: I've said what needs to be said. I'm sorry you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

## [JSFIIDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E8V9f/)

```
 #container {width:100%; min-height:700px; background:blue; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; padding:10px;}
 #box {width:60%; height:70px; background:black;}
 #content {width:70%; height:600px; float:left; background:green; margin-top:10px;}
 #aside {width:30%; height:800px; float:none; clear:both; background:yellow;}
```

You need to clear:both; not only clear:right;

Comment: you got it so right but just found out even when i float it to the right it is horizontally aligned to the content, i want the side bar to shift up and align with the black box when floated right like it is on picture A. sorry i dont mention this

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
#container{
    width:100%; 
    height:700px; 
    background:blue; 
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    padding:10px;
}
#box{
    width:60%; 
    height:70px; 
    background:black;
}
#content{
    width:70%; 
    height:600px; 
    background:green; 
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
}
#aside{
    width:30%; 
    height:800px; 
    background:yellow;
    float:right;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
   #content,#aside{
    display:block;
    float:none;
   }
   #aside{
     margin-top:20px;  
   }
}
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cBh6z/2/)

Answer (score -1):

when you remove the `float:right` from the aside, add `clear:left`.

p.s. if there's nothing floated right, you don't need clear:right